# Installing PCL python on Windows using PIP

Tags: python, point-cloud-library

How to install Point cloud library on python on Windows?

I am working on Anaconda which is python distribution.

So what is the way to install PCL using pip?

If you know any other method please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

To install the library https://github.com/strawlab/python-pcl on windows, follow these steps:

```
-> conda create -n ipk # create a new conda env. 
-> conda activate ipk # activate env.
-> conda update -n base -c defaults conda # update conda
-> conda config --add channels conda-forge # add conda-forge channels 
-> conda install -c sirokujira python-pcl # pcl installation 
-> conda install -c jithinpr2 gtk3 # Gtk+ Gui dependency 
-> conda install -y ipython # install ipython -> conda install -y jupyter # install jupyter
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have some problems with installing PCL on windows you can always use docker on windows, which is very helpful, and in particular my image based on PCL and jupyter:

```
docker pull vadikalp/jupyter-pcl

docker run -p 8888:8888 vadikalp/jypyter-pcl
```

Go to server, create new ipython and  `import pcl`!

Answer (score 0):

PCL depend on Boost, VTK, Eigen, FLANN and QHull.

So it's diffucult to bind PCL to python.

So code PCL in C++.

Comment: I have this link: https://github.com/strawlab/python-pcl. But I cant find a way to install it on windows.